# Anyone have tutorials on how the Gertboard can be utilized? or demos?

Tags: gertboard

I just purchased a gertboard and wanted to see what others have done with it. Are there any good tutorials of how this works and how I can tap into it via the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tech-Fruit recently started a series of [Gertboard tutorials](http://www.tech-fruits.com/archives/6042) which seem pretty good.

Comment: links is gone :(

Comment: Updated link I think but they are overloaded at the moment: http://www.tech-fruits.com/category/gertboard-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

Try raspi.tv
e.g http://raspi.tv/2012/gertboard-software-in-python-2-7-motor-and-leds-programs
Alex has written software to utilize the Gertboard and is likely to be able to answer your questions.